# Terminal stack trace for node process on mac

Tags: bash, macos, sh, stack-trace

Is there a way I can see a stack trace of a generic script as it's running? It crashes opening a file that doesn't exist, but clearly it exists, so I want to see the file from which that call is made. Even a stack trace on ctrl+c would be useful, as I can just try to snipe it just before it happens. I'm on Mac.

Specifically, I'm calling `seth call --debug` from https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/seth#seth-debug .

Comment: [Bash Debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You probably don't need a stack trace. Just run the script with `bash -x` so you see a transcript of all the commands as they're executing. When the error happens, you'll see what filename it's trying to open, and get an idea of why it's failing.

Comment: Unfortunately bash -x doesn't work since executing the sh script doesn't show anything -- I know the filename it's trying to open since it errors that

Comment: Why doesn't `bash -x` work? Is one script executing another script?

Comment: If the file exists but it says that it doesn't, it must be trying to open the wrong file. Maybe it's using a relative pathname and the current directory isn't what you expect it to be. Seeing where it `cd`s to would help.

Comment: Anyway, there aren't really any sophisticated debugging tools built in for `bash` scripts. If you want to see the stack of function calls, you can print the `$FUNCNAME` array.

Comment: How do I install bash debugger? I installed the tar.gz and unzipped, and double clicked configure, but don't know what to do next. I copy pasted my .sh script into the interactive bash -x, but didn't see any additional output. I'm calling `seth call --debug ...` (https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/seth#seth-debug). Knowing where it cd's would be awesome, but I don't see that. `echo $FUNCNAME` is empty, what do I do?

Comment: No idea. I just found it by googling, I've never used it myself.

Comment: If `$FUNCNAME` is empty, you don't have a stack of function calls. What were you expecting a stack trace to show you?

Comment: `$FUNCNAME` is a bash extension. If you're using `sh` or some other shell, it might not exist.

Comment: I see, I ran $FUNCNAME in a different tab in the default Mac terminal. I found something called dtruss on mac but keep getting `dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available` and `$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/dtrace` and get `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/sbin/dtrace: Operation not permitted`

Comment: `seth` isn't a bash script, it's Node.js.

Comment: got it! do you know how to print a stack trace on its crash? or trace what syscalls its doing?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't.

Comment: Does this help? https://gist.github.com/tripleee/0aea6984632c30956329

Comment: @tripleee how do I use/run that? the process only lasts a couple of seconds

Comment: It contains a manual page; you would hook it as a wrapper for the script which is failing. It obviously requires you to be able to rerun the command after creating the hook and repro the problem.

Comment: @tripleee didn't understand why I have to ln anything, but when i do 'bash-5.1$ ./traceback.sh sh scripts/seth_test.sh' I get `traceback for process 9588:
* 9588 /bin/sh ./traceback.sh sh scripts/seth_test.s (cwd...` but no real info.

Comment: That's not how you use it; again, please refer to the documentation embedded in the script itself for guidance.